# Input folder path and return a list of files on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I'm using Tkinter for the code below.

**Goal**

Use filedialog to input the path of a folder to search and return the list of "mp3" files from the folder and put all the "mp3" in one OptionMenu.

```
from tkinter import StringVar, filedialog
import os 
import tkinter
 
root = tkinter.Tk()
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

try:
    if not path:
        print('Canceled')
    else:    
        mp3 = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.lower().endswith('.mp3') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fn))]
        for filename in mp3:    
            clicked = StringVar()
            tkinter.OptionMenu(root, clicked, filename).pack()
except:
    pass

root.mainloop()
```

The code works.

But It's giving me more than 1 OptionMenu.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `OptionMenu` is the widget to put itself in, the second the `StringVar` to put the currently selected value in, the third the default value for the `OptionMenu`, and any other positional arguments will be displayed as options.

So, you need just one `OptionMenu` instance, to which you pass `mp3` as arguments, which you can do with [argument expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) by using `mp3` as an argument but prefixing it with an asterisk (`*`).

Something else to be mentioned is that you usually shoudn't silently ignore any errors - which is why I removed the `try`/`except`. This is the correct code:

```py
from tkinter import StringVar, filedialog
import os 
import tkinter
 
root = tkinter.Tk()
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

if not path:
    print('Canceled')
else:    
    mp3 = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.lower().endswith('.mp3') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fn))]
    clicked = StringVar()
    tkinter.OptionMenu(root, clicked, mp3[0], *mp3).pack()

root.mainloop()
```